# Generic restructure of ruby hash (with depth of 4)

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to convert this HASH into an array of arrays based solely on the position of the key (rather than it's value). ie: I know ahead of time that the first Key will always be PROD/ALPHA, and the second Key will always be a country (that I would like to be able to change in the future at will)

The idea would be to group all servers of the same type (webservers) that are also in the same environment (production) but are located in different farms (UK, USA)

While any suggestions on how to do this are welcome, **I'll be happy to just know that I'm not walking into a dead-end I won't be able to solve.**

Here are some visuals to aid in my explanation:

```
{
  "PROD": {
    "USA": {
      "generic": [
        "nginx-240"
      ],
      "WEB": [
        "nginx-210",
        "nginx-241",
        "nginx-211",
        "nginx-209"
      ],
      "APP": [
        "tomcat-269",
        "tomcat-255",
        "tomcat-119",
        "tomcat-124"
      ]
    },
    "UK": {
      "WEB": [
        "nginx-249",
        "nginx-250",
        "nginx-246",
        "nginx-247",
        "nginx-248"
      ],
      "generic": [
        "tomcat-302"
      ],
      "APP": [
        "tomcat-396",
        "tomcat-156",
        "tomcat-157"
      ]
    }
  },
  "ALPHA": {
    "USA": {
      "WEB": [
        "nginx-144",
        "nginx-146",
        "nginx-145",
        "nginx-175",
        "nginx-173"
      ],
      "APP": [
        "tomcat-204",
        "tomcat-206"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The expectation is that data from the **lowest level** in the hash would be grouped together.

Again the idea is that all Production app servers (both from UK and USA) are grouped together in the following kind of pattern:

**PROD_UK_APP** would be represented by 
**["tomcat-396","tomcat-156","tomcat-157"]** as these are the lowest branches of the tree PROD->UK->applicationserver

```
[
 [
  [PROD_UK_APP],[PROD_USA_APP]
 ],
 [
  [PROD_UK_WEB],[PROD_USA_WEB]
 ]
]
```

New list..

```
[
 [
  [ALPHA_USA_WEB]
 ],
 [
  [ALPHA_USA_APP],
 [
[
```

Again the idea is to keep this generic. Is this something that is practically achievable or am I likely to require some degree of hardcoding to ensure it always works? The idea is that if tomorrow UK becomes JAPAN, it will still work in exactly the same way, comparing between the APP and WEB tier of UK, and JAPAN (separating ALPHA from PROD).

EDIT: my attempt to try and sort it:

```
  def walk
    a = []
    myhash.each do |env, data|
      data.each do |dc, tier|
        tier.each do |x, y|
          a << y
        end
      end
    end
    p a
  end

[["nginx240"], ["nginx210", "nginx241", "nginx211", "nginx209"], ["tomcat269", "tomcat255", "tomcat119", "tomcat124"], ["nginx249", "nginx250", "nginx246", "nginx247", "nginx248"], ["tomcat302"], ["tomcat396", "tomcat156", "tomcat157"], ["nginx144", "nginx146", "nginx145", "nginx175", "nginx173"], ["tomcat204", "tomcat206"]]
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have some good data there. The next step before asking a Stack Overflow question is to try something, anything, to solve your problem. You need to have some Ruby code in here. You can't "refactor" nothing.

Comment: Np, but my attempt is embarassing.

Comment: Embarrassing or not, it shows you're committed to solving the problem and we'll respect you more for that than expecting us to come up with the answer for you.

Comment: Curiosity question: Did the hash exist as a JSON prior to being converted to a hash?

Answer (score 1):

I think I follow what you're looking for and you should get what you're after with:

```
myhash.values.each_with_object([]) do |by_country, out_arr|
  by_country.values.each do |by_type|
    out_arr << by_type.values
  end
end
```

which would return:

```
[
  [
    [
      "nginx-240"
    ],
    [
      "nginx-210",
      "nginx-241",
      "nginx-211",
      "nginx-209"
    ],
    [
      "tomcat-269",
      "tomcat-255",
      "tomcat-119",
      "tomcat-124"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "nginx-249",
      "nginx-250",
      "nginx-246",
      "nginx-247",
      "nginx-248"
    ],
    [
      "tomcat-302"
    ],
    [
      "tomcat-396",
      "tomcat-156",
      "tomcat-157"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "nginx-144",
      "nginx-146",
      "nginx-145",
      "nginx-175",
      "nginx-173"
    ],
    [
      "tomcat-204",
      "tomcat-206"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Piece by piece

- Take your hash, disgard the keys and just create an array of values.
- iterate over the values (array of hashes by country) and initialize an array to return.
- for each hash that by_country points to, again take the values, to drop into the by type(?) hashes
- iterate over your by_type hashes and again take the values of each
- push each return array into the array you want to return

Comment: Your suggestion is very close to but not quite what I am trying to achieve and has certainly given me a direction to investigate.

Many thanks!

Comment: @ARL I updated the answer without `Array#flatten` which I think matches what you're looking for. If not let me know.